# How to select values from three or more related tables in sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three table in related in my database. `Grammars`, `Users`, and `Organizations`.
`Grammars` table are related to `users` table through field `creator` which is type `int` and is a foreign key from `users id`. 
Next we have the `organizations` table which in turn is related with the `users` table. `Users` table field `organization` of type `id` is foreign key to table `organizations id`. 
How can I select for example a grammar by `id`, then select its corresponding `creator` information and then the corresponding `organization` information the user belongs to??

`describe grammars;`

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name             | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| short_name       | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| domain           | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| url              | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| seo_friendly_url | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| encoding         | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| distribution     | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| project          | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| creator          | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| language         | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| link             | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| creation_date    | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_update      | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| schema           | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type             | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| organization     | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`describe Users;`

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name   | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name    | varchar(40)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username     | varchar(30)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| password     | varbinary(32)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(80)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| organization | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| group        | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 1       |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`describe Organizations;`

```
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name               | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| department         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| communication_info | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When I try

```
SELECT Grammars.name AS name, Grammars.description AS description,
Domains.name AS domain,Types.name AS type, Languages.name AS language, 
Encodings.name AS encoding, 
Organizations.name AS organization_name, Organizations.department AS organization_department, Organizations.communication_info AS organization_comm_info,
Users.last_name AS creator_last_name, Users.first_name AS creator_first_name, Users.email AS creator_email,
Projects.name AS project_name, Projects.short_name AS project_short_name, Projects.url AS project_url,
Projects.funding AS project_funding, Projects.funder AS project_funder,
Projects.start_date AS project_start_date, Projects.end_date AS project_end_date
FROM Grammars 
LEFT JOIN Domains ON Grammars.domain=Domains.id 
LEFT JOIN Types ON Grammars.type=Types.id 
LEFT JOIN Languages ON Grammars.language=Languages.id 
LEFT JOIN Projects ON Grammars.project = Projects.id
LEFT JOIN Encodings ON Grammars.encoding = Encodings.id
LEFT JOIN Users ON Grammars.creator = Users.id
LEFT JOIN Organizations ON Users.organization = Organizations.id
WHERE Grammars.id = 3 ;
```

i get empty set while there are values. Any suggestions??

Comment: which id is this "WHERE Grammars.id = id;"? do you want the records in which sequence Horizontal or Vertical ?

Comment: You state that you have 3 tables in your database but you are joining more than 3 tables, do you have these other tables, like `Domains`, Types`, etc?

Comment: Yes of course i just didn't inserted their description because the query worked ok until i inserted the last join between Users and Organizations in the query.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why this query is not returning any data is because there's no row in Grammars that accomplish:
   Grammars.id = id

If you're using LEFT JOIN, it will not restrict Grammars returns.
What is the value of "id" ? Looking at your table's descriptions I see that you have an "id" field in every one of them... You should qualify this fieldname and get sure that the condition is met for some rows.

Comment: Well this is a stored procedure thats why you see the id. I Call it with id=3 and i still get no results (empty set).

Comment: And there exists a row in Grammars with id=3 ?